# User input does not work within a java thread. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, multithreading, user-input, try-finally

Ok, I am trying to make a simple chat server and client. This program is the chat server.
I have two threads that are running. The first thread handles all of the clients and binds each new client to a new socket using ServerSocket and the second thread for now allows the user to send a message to the connected client. I cannot, however, get user input from within this thread! The statement "String inputvar = br.readLine()" will not execute! What am I doing wrong?

```
public void relay() throws IOException
        {
            new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                        try{
                            try
                            {
                            while (true)
                            {

                                Socket socket2 = null;       
                                Socket socket1 = socketmethod(socket2,0); 
                                System.out.println(socket1);
                                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                                while (socket1 != null)
                                { 
                                        PrintWriter outputriver = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
                                        boolean cfd = true;
                                        while(cfd==true)
                                        {

                                            System.out.println("this worked");
                                            System.out.print("Message: ");
                                            String inputvar = br.readLine();
                                            System.out.println("this worked2");
                                            if (inputvar.equals("disconnect_now"))
                                            {
                                                cfd = false;
                                            }
                                            outputriver.println("Unknown User: " + inputvar);

                                        }
                                }   
                            }
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                              System.out.println("error 1");
                            }
                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {

                            System.out.println("Unexpected error: IOException in thread2");
                        }
                }
            }).start();
```

Comment: May I suggest to use a little less indentation spaces? I agree, nowadays' widescreens are wide. But SO's content area is not and horizontal scrolling is cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from your code where you are initiating accepting your client connection. I would expect to see something like this...

```
public void replay() {
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

        while(true) {
            try {
                final Socket connection = serverSocket.accept();

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                            String value = br.readLine();

                            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), true);
                            pw.println(value);
```

However if you are accepting multiple client requests having many threads, you will have them block on br.readline() as they compete for `System.in`

Also make sure that your input is sending the correct "new line" character(s) in order to fulfill the `readline()` requirements.